# Python 3.5. How to avoid WinError 6 invalid handle in google results Selenium scraper?

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling

My program scrapes Google search results by opening Selenium windows and looking for "contact" pages. Unfortunately I am getting this error - below - that stops the program in its tracks. What to do to resolve it? Thanks for help
This is the program:

```
#THIS SEARCHES FOR ANY NUMBER OF SEARCH TERMS PLUS OTHER WORDS
#AND SCRAPES FOR EMAILS THE FIRST X NUMBERS OF RESULTS
#THEN DOUBLE CHECKS WITH SELENIUM BY OPENING CONTACT LINKS AND SCRAPING WITH REGEX

import requests, re, bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time,random

def google_this_for_emails():                #Googles and gets the first few links
    search_terms = ['Barcelona','Madrid']
    added_terms = 'seleccion de personal executive search email contact? @'
    number_of_sites = 10   #NUMBER OF SITES (SEARCH RESULTS) TO PARSE FOR EMAILS
    #added_terms = 'email contact? @'
    # search_terms = ['Doctor Hemimegalencefalia HEMISFERECTOMIA','Cirugia Hemimegalencefalia HEMISFERECTOMIA','Surgery Hemimegalencephaly HEMISPHERECTOMY','chirurgia Hemimegalencefalia HEMISFERECTOMY', 'Chirurgie Hemimegalencefalia HEMISFERECTOMY']


    global scrapedEmails
    scrapedEmails = []

    #This searches for certain keywords in Google and parses results with BS
    for el in search_terms:
        webpage = 'http://google.com/search?q=' + str(el) + str(added_terms)
        print('\n Searching for the terms...', el,added_terms)
        headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
        res = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
        #res.raise_for_status()

        statusCode = res.status_code
        if statusCode == 200:
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
            serp_res_rawlink = soup.select('.r a')

            dicti = []                  #This gets the href links
            for link in serp_res_rawlink:
                url = link.get('href')
                if 'pdf' not in url:
                    dicti.append(url)

            dicti_url = []              #This cleans the "url?q=" from link
            for el in dicti:
                if '/url?q=' in el:
                    result = (el.strip('/url?q='))
                    dicti_url.append(result)
            #print(dicti_url)

            global dicti_pretty_links
            dicti_pretty_links = []     #This cleans the gibberish at end of url
            for el in dicti_url[0:(number_of_sites)]:
                pretty_url = el.partition('&')[0]
                dicti_pretty_links.append(pretty_url)
            print(dicti_pretty_links)


            # for el in dicti_pretty_links:
            # #######START OF THE BS CHECK FOR EMAILS BY REGEX #################
            #     #This opens page in BS for parsing emails
            #     webpage = (el)
            #     headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
            #     res = requests.get(webpage, headers=headers)
            #
            #     statusCode = res.status_code
            #     if statusCode == 200:
            #         soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
            #
            #         #This is the first way to search for an email in soup, "MO"
            #         emailRegex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.+.+]+)', re.VERBOSE)
            #         mo = emailRegex.findall(res.text)
            #         print('THIS BELOW IS MO')
            #         print(mo)
            #         for el in mo:
            #             if el not in scrapedEmails:
            #                 scrapedEmails.append(el)
            #
            #         #This is the second way to search for an email in soup, "MAILTOS":
            #         mailtos = soup.select('a[href^=mailto]')
            #         print('THIS BELOW IS MAILTOS')
            #         print(mailtos)
            #
            #         dicti_cleaner = []
            #         target = re.compile(r'mailto')
            #         for el in mailtos:
            #             mo = target.search(str(el))
            #             dicti_cleaner.append(el)
            #
            #         temp = []
            #         for el in dicti_cleaner:
            #             pretty_url = str(el).partition(':')[2]
            #             second_url = str(pretty_url).partition('"')[0]
            #             temp.append(second_url)
            #
            #         for el in temp:
            #             if el not in scrapedEmails:
            #                 scrapedEmails.append(el)
            #     #######END OF THE BS CHECK FOR EMAILS BY REGEX #################


            for el in dicti_pretty_links:
            #######START OF THE SELENIUM CHECK FOR "CONTACT" PAGES #################
                browser = webdriver.Firefox()  #This converts page into Selenium object
                page = browser.get(el)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1.5))
                try:                                #Tries to open "contact" link
                    contact_link = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('ontact')
                    if contact_link:
                        contact_link.click()
                except:
                    pass    #Silently ignores exception
                html = browser.page_source          #Loads up the page for Regex search
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1.5))
                emailRegex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.+.+]+)', re.VERBOSE)
                mo = emailRegex.findall(html)
                print('THIS BELOW IS SEL_emails_MO for',el)
                print(mo)
                for el in mo:
                    if el not in scrapedEmails:     #Checks if emails is/adds to ddbb
                        scrapedEmails.append(el)
                browser.close()
                #######END OF THE SELENIUM CHECK FOR "CONTACT" PAGES #################

    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1.5))    #INSERTS HUMAN-LIKE RANDOM DELAY

    print(100*'-')
    print(len(search_terms),'terms have been searched, for a total of',number_of_sites,'search results each')
    print(len(search_terms)*number_of_sites,'pages have been scraped for emails.')
    print('A total of ',len(scrapedEmails),'emails have been found')
    print('These are the emails found:')
    print(scrapedEmails)
    print(100*'-')

google_this_for_emails()
```

AND THIS IS THE OUTPUT OF THE PROGRAM ABOVE:

```
C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/SK/PycharmProjects/untitled/google_search_open_tabs.py

 Searching for the terms... Barcelona seleccion de personal executive search email contact? @
['http://www.dmasesores.com/', 'https://www.hays.es/', 'http://adhocexecutive.com/', 'http://www.experis.es/', 'http://www.bpmes.es/', 'http://www.thinkingpeoplerecursoshumanos.es/seleccion-de-personal-y-executive-search/servicios/', 'http://www.headway.es/', 'http://www.trsearch.net/politica_privacidad.html', 'http://www.luxetalent.es/empresas/', 'http://www.contalento.es/seleccion/']
THIS BELOW IS SEL_emails_MO for http://www.dmasesores.com/
['info@dmasesores.com', 'info@dmasesores.com', 'info@dmasesores.com', 'info@dmasesores.com']
THIS BELOW IS SEL_emails_MO for https://www.hays.es/
[]
THIS BELOW IS SEL_emails_MO for http://adhocexecutive.com/
['info@adhocexecutive.com']
THIS BELOW IS SEL_emails_MO for http://www.experis.es/
[]
THIS BELOW IS SEL_emails_MO for http://www.bpmes.es/
['web@scdyss.com', 'info@bpmes.es']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SK/PycharmProjects/untitled/google_search_open_tabs.py", line 132, in <module>
    google_this_for_emails()
  File "C:/Users/SK/PycharmProjects/untitled/google_search_open_tabs.py", line 100, in google_this_for_emails
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()  #This converts page into Selenium object
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 67, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env)
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 845, in __init__
    _cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in _cleanup
    res = inst._internal_poll(_deadstate=sys.maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1255, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please read this then edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: well, it appears that you're having some sort of issue opening the Firefox webdriver. re-install it, maybe?

Comment: @IanAuld I thought I was doing that by commenting the code that does not apply. I don't feel confident enough to delete the rest of the code. I am a beginner and feel that you guys better see more than less, in case I delete something that's related to something else, thus making you guys waste your time because I did so.

Comment: @n1c9 I'll try that, thanks. Any idea of what may be going wrong? Is this a common problem? I thought the problem was on my code. Is there anything I can do to avoid connecting to pages that don't respond?

Comment: @skeitel: Frankly, I do a lot of webscraping and I've never seen it before. I was just guessing from the stack trace.  to avoid connecting to pages that don't respond, try something like:

Comment: `try:
    page = browser.get(el)
except OSError:
    continue`

That'd make it run past the OSErrors, but not recommended for production code because it may mask some valuable error codes.edit: spacing and indentation doesn't transfer over in comments, but I'm sure you can adapt it. :-)